# Is there a finite amount of Siege Worms and Krakens?

Tags: civilization-beyond-earth

In Beyond Earth I was wondering if Siege Worms and Krakens were spawned by Alien Nests, or is a limited number of them were scattered across the map when it was generated?

Is it possible to elminate these aliens from the game?

Comment: I have a quest to kill siege worms, and I haven't seen a single one since getting the quest. I've only seen one all game, and it was pretty early.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible to prevent them from spawning, but there is an infinite number that can spawn. Kraken won't spawn on visible tiles, so you can get vision of the ocean to prevent them from spawning. Seige worms spawn from alien nests located on xenomass tiles, so you need to position a unit on, or gain cultural control over, all the xenomass tiles to prevent alien nests from reappearing, and then no more worms will be able to spawn

Comment: Seige Worms spawn from Alien Nests? are you sure? Its just that I keep finding them, very early in the game, far removed from any Alien Nests.

Comment: @Jimmery I think that when the game starts a bunch of aliens are generated anywhere, but following that the "mid-game" spawns seem to be from alien nests only.

Comment: If they can spawn outside nests, they still dont spawn on visible tiles

Comment: Do the tiles only need to be invisible from the human players for krakens to spawn, or does observation by an AI player also prevent them from spawning?

Comment: AI player units also prevent them from spawning.

Answer (score 1):

I am not certain about Siege Worms, but Krakens are certainly not limited. I just finished a game of 320+ turns, and was still killing off Krakens. Unless there was a hidden nest somewhere, they were simply spawning in the middle of the ocean. I would assume the same is true of Siege Worms, although I imagine the spawn rate is much lower than other land aliens.